# mySQL - Create 4-fields primary key/index to stop duplicates?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `locations` that, among other fields, has the fields:

```
IMEI: VARCHAR(15) foreign key references devices.IMEI
latitude: DECIMAL(10,6)
longitude: DECIMAL(10,6)
datetime: DATETIME
```

Sometimes, my server stores duplicates, i.e all of the fields above are equal, meaning `a given device (IMEI)` was at `latitude,longitude` at `datetime`. I want to block all inserts that have these four fields equal to any other row on the table.

I'm not sure if I should use index or primary key. If it helps, these fields are used on selects/filters all the time.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use a composit primary key.

Comment: Is the table referenced to from other tables and is any of these fields under **any** circumstances updated? If answer to the first question or both is yes I would not make those columns primary key...

Comment: @SimoKivistö, no, no fields are ever updated in any circumstances at both tables.

Comment: Ok, if there are no foreign key references to the table, you might as well go with the 4-field primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the composite primary key by altering the existing table

```
ALTER TABLE locations ADD PRIMARY KEY(IMEI, latitude, longitude, datetime);
```

Or you can define the key while creating the table

```
DECLARE @locations TABLE (
...,
PRIMARY KEY(IMEI, latitude, longitude, datetime)
);
```

Comment: So, a primary key is better than an index, I suppose?

Comment: Using primary key you take these advantages out of the box: 
a primary key is implicitly `UNIQUE`,  a primary key can never be `NULL`

Comment: Oh, I see. That applies to my table, so I will use a primary key then. Thank you!